# Read/Send sms from wifi modem in c#

Tags: sms

I have modem which is work on browser as wifi and when i connect to pc it becomes virtual router having ip address and DHCP settings. Now i want to use this wifi dongle as like long code or sms gateway.Also this modem is working on browser so it dont have port for communication to pc. How i can do this i.e. take sms which is stored in device local memory not on cloud and send it to clients. I cant use AT commands for read/write sms coz AT commodes only work when we have port number...pls suggest if any idea...is it possible?? I want implement this feature asp.net MVC5
Thanks in advance